# MSdeploy skip rule for directory in root only

Tags: msdeploy

I have a need to skip a folder named images in my Visual Studio 2017 web app project but ONLY the one in the root of the web app. I have successfully configured other skip rules and they work, except that I found a problem with absolute path expressions unintentionally matching subdirectories buried in some template code. In my wpp.targets file for example:

```
<MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipFilesInFilesFolder">
    <SkipAction></SkipAction>
    <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
    <AbsolutePath>\\images$</AbsolutePath>
    <XPath></XPath>
</MsDeploySkipRules>
```

Then ALL folders named "images" are skipped, no matter where they are. Which makes sense, my regular expression catches any folder named images period. How do I craft the right expression to skip ONLY the root images folder but not any that may be buried in some plugin folder who knows where buried in my project? I can't make a definitive catalog of all images folders because I may add another plugin in the future, so listing them all explicitly isn't a good option at all.

I tried using `<AbsolutePath>NameOfWebApp\\images$</AbsolutePath>` but that was ignored.

How in the world can I specify the ROOT folder only? I found elsewhere that using "NameOfWebApp\images$" should work, but it is completely ignored.